# Django - 'Created by'-Field

Tags: python, django, model

In my Django-Project, I made a form to create a model. When the form is sent/the model is created, I want to reference the current user in an 'author'-Field.
I'm having some troubles with that.

```
author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

I just want to have the creator of the model saved in this field. Is that possible?

Comment: Show me your model. You should have there field `author = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='authors')`. When you have this.. in ModelForm you will not need ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Hmmm, had a ForeignKey, changed it to OneToOneField, didnt knew this yet. What do I need then?

Comment: Did a really dirty JS-Solution. Wrote the user id in a hidden field and set value of Option-Field to user id. Works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the model should look like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Some form:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name']
```

And finally the view, which makes it happen.

```
class BookView(FormView):
    form_class = BookForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        book = form.save(commit=False) 
        book.author = self.request.user 
        book.save()
```

But remember to ensure that there is a logged in user.